# Canonical question for issues relating to upgrading to Discord.js v12

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, canonical

There are a lot of questions relating to results from upgrading to Discord.js v12, most commonly dealing with the addition of managers and having to use `.cache`:

- [discord.js V12 'filter' undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61841794/8289918)
- [Discord.js Issue with roles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63866088/8289918)
- [TypeError: member.guild.channels.get is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60883461/8289918)
- [TypeError: message.guild.members.get is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61785866/8289918)
- [TypeError: client.users.get is not a function discord.js V12](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61844119/8289918)
- [bot.users.get is no longer a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63020775/8289918)
- [TypeError: message.guild.members.filter is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62460435/8289918)
- [TypeError: message.guild.channels.filter is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60852410/8289918)
- [discord.js TypeError: server.roles.find is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62053864/8289918)
- [TypeError: servguild.roles.find is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60600828/8289918)
- [TypeError: message.guild.roles.find is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60992797/8289918)
- [TypeError: message.guild.channels.find is not a function discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61861693/8289918)
- [Error: TypeError: message.guild.channels.find is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61714261/8289918)
- [guild.members.forEach is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60918836/8289918)
- [TypeError: message.member.roles.some is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60983028/8289918)
- [TypeError: oldMember.roles.every is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63659949/8289918)
- [TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchMembers' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63101977/8289918)
- [TypeError: reaction.fetchMembers is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61026378/8289918)
- [TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined, Discord.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61760520/typeerror-cannot-read-property-add-of-undefined-discord-js)
- [I can't use the code I use in version v11.6.4 I use version v12.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63769877/8289918)
- [How to get user by id in discordjs 12?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62383850/8289918)
- [Discord.js TypeError: message.guild.createRole is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62828010/8289918)
- probably more questions…

Should there be a single canonical question, explaining the most common v12 breaking changes and linking to the [updating to v12 guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html), that we can mark these questions as a duplicate of?

I propose two different solutions:

1. **Make one of these existing questions the canonical.** An existing question with a suitable, high-quality answer, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60605780/8289918), could be used so that a new question does not need to be created. However, this question may be too specific and not address some of the other changes in v12.
2. **Create a new question.** A self-answered question could be created which addresses the main breaking changes in v12. We can then mark the other questions as duplicates of this one. This is the solution I prefer because it would be a single, high-quality question/answer that covers most of the issues from upgrading to v12, and is similar to what I did with [this question on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/188492).

Comment: feel free to ping me once (2) is set up, then I can link some other questions there via duplicate votes

Comment: @JonasWilms I've created [the canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63911361/82899180)

Comment: done, couldn't find any further questions when briefly going through the last few newest questions ... hopefully created enough visibility so that it'll grow naturally from now on.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with your second solution:

> 2. Create a new question.

As you have stated, a lot of the existing questions are too specific and don't really represent the issue properly; making one of these questions the canonical doesn't really make sense, as the title poorly represents the real underlying issue.

A new question would be much clearer and would ensure users are more likely to come across the question when searching with terms like **v12** and **migration**.

A new answer would also be able to go into more depth about the changes from Discord.js v11 to v12, while also providing extra links for users to find more information, which might help to fix their issue.

**Here are some links that could be provided:**

- [Migration guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html)
- [Changelog](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/releases/tag/12.0.0)

Comment: Somebody seems to have upvoted the question and this answer at about the same time as me getting an upvote on 2 of my Discord.js answers. **Coincidence? I Think Not!** *BTW: thanks.*

Answer (score 7):

I've created [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63911361/8289918) as a canonical question. Feel free to leave any feedback.